# sqlite: how to populate new column with values once new column has been added?

Tags: sqlite

After the syntax,

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN newcolumn float
```

How do I insert new values into this `newcolumn`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET newcolumn = <something>
```

Comment: And if `<something>` is not a single value, then I need a `where` clause and insert each record by row? So I'm getting that this is probably not the way to go if I have about 10,000 values to insert...

Comment: Where is the data you're inserting coming from?  If it's not computed from something already in the database then row-by-row is the only way to go.

Comment: I see - yes, it's actually computed in R and I was interfacing with RSQLite. Thanks.

Comment: Truly not helpful answer when there are millions of rows.